# Is it possible to count sub-items in view in Drupal 7?

Tags: views, ubercart

I want to count nodes in sub-categories (taxonomy terms using) and view result to category field. how to do this in views?

Example:

category with counter http://3.reshleon.z8.ru/catalog/bytovaya-tehnika

items in category, needs to count them http://3.reshleon.z8.ru/catalog/42

Answer (score 1):

In views, there is an one field called global counter. Render it and it will give you the count. If you wish you could also hide it via display setting.